# Database in suspect mode

Tags: sql-server, recovery, corruption, dbcc-checkdb

I'm experiencing a tough issue for me. When I was updating some columns into the database I have previously installed, the main memory corruption led the database jump into the suspect mode. I follow the following steps to recover the database:

```
1. EXEC sp_resetstatus 'dbNSFP';

2. ALTER DATABASE dbNSFP 
   SET EMERGENCY;

3. DBCC CHECKDB('dbNSFP');

3. ALTER DATABASE dbNSFP 
   SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;

4. DBCC CHECKDB (dbNSFP, REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS);

5. ALTER DATABASE dbNSFP SET MULTI_USER;
```

When I was in the 1st step, MS SQL Server Management Studio gives:

> Warning: You must recover this database prior to access.
>
> Completion time: 2020-06-21T11:33:19.6094013-04:00

When I was in the 2nd step, the Studio reports an error:

> Msg 5011, Level 14, State 7, Line 3 User does not have permission to
> alter database 'dbNSFP', the database does not exist, or the database
> is not in a state that allows access checks. Msg 5069, Level 16, State
> 1, Line 3 ALTER DATABASE statement failed.
>
> Completion time: 2020-06-21T11:34:47.5199727-04:00

I've been search for this solution for several days. Some cues are pointing to change the alter permission to the user. However, I'm a SA user, SA should hold all CONTROL permissions. I have been stuck here for days. I hope someone could help me out.

Comment: Memory corruption should not force database to go in recovery mode, may be something different is happening. What is status of DB right now ?

Comment: the DB is in suspect